# SSIS Package bypasses task after Script Task completes

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis, script-task

All:  I'm using Visual Studio 2013.  I'm at my wits end with this:  For some odd reason my package ends abruptly at the highlighted area below (It's supposed to go directly to "Update File Log" execute SQL task but it ends at the previous Script Task and completely ignores it.

Any thoughts?  Thanks.

[image]

Please see code below.  The error I get is that absolutely useless "exception has been thrown by target of an invocation".  This occurs at the arrow indicator, right before the sqlcommand fires:

```
SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection()
myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)
(Dts.Connections["DBconn"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);

MessageBox.Show(tableDDL.ToString());

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(tableDDL, myADONETConnection);  <===
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("TABLE IS CREATED");


//Load the data from DataTable to SQL Server Table.
SqlBulkCopy blk = new SqlBulkCopy(myADONETConnection);
blk.DestinationTableName = "[" + filename + "]";
blk.WriteToServer(dt);

MessageBox.Show("TABLE IS filled");
```

Here is the tableDDL syntax that is getting created - anyone see an issue?

[image]

Comment: Does "No - Create table" run? Are your constraints set to "and"? You really need to post a screenshot of the property pages for the constraints. Also reduce to the simplest repro possible 0 i.e. don't post a screenshot with _fx_ indicators if that is not the simplest repro

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid:Thanks, I edited the picture to reflect that.  And yes, the SQL task (no-create table) does indeed run.

Comment: Edit:  The Script Task (no-create table) runs successfully, not SQL task.

Comment: Does the script task return a 'success' in it's code? Does the SSIS log indicate that it completed successfully?

Comment: I posted the above edit screenshot.  I'm not sure what you mean, or how to check.  All I know is my table got created and the execution results show the above.  Also, if there was a failure I would be notified (big red "X"), no?

Comment: In your posted log, "Update File Log" is actually run.... although it is not indented where I expect it

Comment: Yes, I'm confused.  I don't understand what is happening.  It stands to reason if there is an arrow from one task to another, the trailing task WILL BE executed unless there is an error.  This is extremely frustrating as I have deadlines but can't get past this.

Comment: In your log, it _is_ executed

Comment: thx for the input, but this isn't helping.  I've had enough for one night.

Comment: are you sure you are pointing to right db may be its pointing different db then what you expected

Comment: @Mani:  Now for some reason I'm getting errors where before I was not.  I updated my post above with some more screenshots.  I show the code where the error occurs, and the DDL syntax that I'm trying to create.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think I got the error message:  I had to delete my connection manager and make a new one.  For some reason, that worked.  My original problem still stands:  I don't know why the Update File Log SQL task is being ignored (highlighted yellow circle above).

Comment: can you put some dummy script task instead of execute sql task and try to run it

Comment: Look at your log - it is not being ignored. Your log indicates it is being run. What makes you think it's not running?

Comment: Does "Update File Log" expect both predecessors to be completed? If so, it would explain why it doesn't get executed (since only 1 of the predecessors will be executed)

Comment: Both sides cannot complete as i bet the f(x) is boolean. Copy the final task and put on both paths

Comment: @All:  You are correct.  Removing one of the paths did the trick. I was under the impression either of the two paths to the last task (update file log) would fire regardless of the path.   I think I could solve this by placing the 3 tasks (does table exist, yes, no) in a container and then have a path to the update file log task?  Thank you all for your patience.

Comment: See second sentence of my first comment: _Are your constraints set to and?_

Comment: Both the he "Yes" and "NO" precedent were set to "Logical AND".

Comment: If you change that to OR then only one of the constraints needs to be satisfied